# Acumatica REST API - StockItem - Query on getting Multiple UOM and Branch wise Qty

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

In Acumatica REST API - StockItem 
Question 1: How to get the multiple UOM of a Product ?
Question 2: How to get Branch wise Qty of a Product ?

I am using the url https://sandbox.kimballinc.com/AcumaticaERP/entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem?$filter=InventoryID eq '12345'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get Qty of the product per warehouse you can use  expand = warehouseDetails parameter

```
{{sitename}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem?$expand=WarehouseDetails&$filter=InventoryID eq '12345'
```

As for UOM, you get them right away with you initial request. If you are talking about UOM conversions, you use expand = UOMConversions

```
{{sitename}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem?$expand=UOMConversions&$filter=InventoryID eq '12345'
```

If you need more details about entity schema, you can observe endpoint schema on Web Service Endpoints form inside Acumatica ERP.

However, if you want to retrieve both of them at the same time in Acumatica ERP 219r1 or earlier, you will have to change the request and use retrieval of record by key fields request:
https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(13))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=52c97a83-1fa1-40e9-8219-52a89a91f2da
(Starting from 2019r2 version you can retrieve both using filter)

So, instead of $filter parameter, you modify url itself, like that:

```
{{sitename}}/entity/Default/18.200.001/StockItem/12345?$expand=UOMConversions,WarehouseDetails
```

(12345 here is Inventory ID)

Comment: I want to know how to use the contents inside UOMConversions. For my endpoint and one product got a UOMConversions content as

Comment: "UOMConversions": [
            {
                "rowNumber": 1,
                "note": null,
                "ConversionFactor": {
                    "value": 1
                },
                "FromUOM": {
                    "value": "EACH"
                },
                "MultiplyDivide": {
                    "value": "Multiply"
                },
                "ToUOM": {
                    "value": "FOOT"
                }            }
        ]

Comment: I want to know how these UOM details are used. How many UOM's are inside here.